# How to show values of a list in a format rather than [x1,x2,x3] in JSP?

Tags: jsp, struts2, jstl, checkboxlist

**Short Story:**

I have a field as following List < Integer > engine = new ArrayList(); when I use ${engine} in jsp it shows its values in [x1,x2] format but I need it to be engine=x1,engine=x2 to make a link. How to do it? Another option would be make the back-end to accept values in [x1,x2] format.

**Long Story:**

I have a form which has two checkboxlists, user is looking for cars based on few items such as number of their doors and their engine power. Once form is submitted all car brands which any number of their cars are matched to search criteria will be shown. Once user clicks on either of the brands all of its matched cars will be shown.

```
 ...
 <s:checkboxlist name="engine" label="Engine" list="@com.car.interfaces.Lists@Engine"/>
 <s:checkboxlist name="door" label="door" list="@com.car.interfaces.Lists@Door"/>
 ....
```

I used both following codes to show the results but output of both is in this format [1000,2000]

```
   <s:property value="%{engine}"/>   
   ${engine}
```

When the results are shown, links will be created as following

```
<a href ="....?${engine}&${door}&....">View Cars</a>
which would change to following
<a href="....?engine=[1000,2000]
              &door=[2,4,5]&.....">View Cars</a>
```

When I click on the link it is unable to find the items; however, if I change the format of values to 1000,2000 it works.

I know, one way would be using a for look to go through all of the items and create the string of items in desired format, but is there any other method to do it?

```
public static final Map Engine = new TreeMap() {
        {
            put(1000, "Small");
            put(2000, "Good");
            put(3000, "Standard");
            put(4000, "Powerful");
            put(5000, "Excellent");
        }
    ;
    };
```

Comment: You are doing something wrong. The parameters in url should be in the `engine=1000&engine=2000` format. How do you creating this url?

Comment: @AleksandrM thats my question as well, the code creates the addresses as engine=[1000,2000] and I would like them to be like engine=1000,2000 or what you explained. Please read the 'short story' part of my question thanks.

Comment: But you haven't shown **how** do you create such url. And what about checkboxes how do they fit in your question? Do you have form? Why do you create url by yourself?

Comment: @AleksandrM I included my code of checkboxlists and also shown and explained why and how I am creating the urls. Do you have form? "I have a form which has two checkboxlists..." Why do you create url by yourself? "Once form is submitted all car brands which any number of their cars are matched to search criteria will be shown. Once user CLICKS on either of the brands all of its matched cars will be shown." To clarify, a form is created user select items of its checkboxlist and submit the form, results will be shown and user is able to click on each of the results to view them in more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Struts2 tags to create url parameters from a list. The `<s:param>` tag will expand list passed in `value` attribute to `param_name=val1&param_name=val2` format.

```
<s:url>
  <s:param name="engine" value="engine" />
  <s:param name="door" value="door" />
</s:url>
```

Comment: I used that it works but it seems everytime I submit the page and the results are shown need to refresh the page before editing the search criteria as without refreshing the page the values of parameters do not get change.

Comment: @JackMoore: That is other question. Your OP was about url generation.

Answer (score 0):

just change your line of code to

```
<s:checkboxlist name="engine" label="Engine" list="engine"/>
```

The value for attribute `list` should be name of your list `List < Integer > engine = new ArrayList();`  no need to give ${engine}

My suggestion :

Create list of bean objects :

```
Class Engine{
int enginePower;
String description;
}
```

Now `List <Engine> engineList = new ArrayList();`

So finally your checBoxList

```
<s:checkboxlist name="engineArray" label="Engine" list="engineList" listValue="description" listKey="enginePower"/>
```

You can access the values as below :

```
public class Handler extends ActionSupport{

      private String[] engineArray;

public void setEngineArray(String[] engineArray){

        this.engineArray= engineArray;
    }

@Override
    public String execute() throws Exception {

        // use the checkbox values here

        return Action.SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

I guess this is what you are looking for

Comment: At present, I am using a map as values are pur(1000,"small"); pur(2000,"good"); pur(3000,"power");

Comment: It is not possible, as I am using a class to receive the search items, take class Items { private List<Integer> engine; .... as an example.

Comment: You can create different class name like "EngineDTO" or some thing as you wish

Comment: whats your idea about j888's answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can format the results in JSP as following: You can add the comma in the loop or using the provided functions.

```
 <c:forEach items="${engine}" var="currentItem" varStatus="status">
       <c:set var="myVar" value="${status.first ? ' ' : myVar} ${currentItem}" />
 </c:forEach>

 <c:set var="string1" value="${myVar}"/>
 <c:set var="string2" value="${fn:split(string1, ' ')}" />
 <c:set var="string3" value="${fn:join(string2, ',')}" />

 <p>String (3) : ${string3}</p>
```